# Check if words in one dataframe appear in another (python 3, pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Problem:  I have two data frames and want to remove any duplicates/partial duplicates between them.

```
 DF1                 DF2

 **Phrases**         **Phrases**  
 Little Red          Little Red Corvette
 Grow Your           Grow Your Beans
 James Bond          James Dean
 Tom Brady
```

I want to remove "Little Red" and "Grow Your" phrases from DF1 and then combine the two DF so that the final product looks like:

```
 DF3
 Little Red Corvette
 Grow Your Beans
 James Bond
 James Dean
 Tom Brady
```

Just a note, I only want to remove the phrases from DF1 if ALL the words appear in a phrase in DF2 (e.g. Little Red Vs. Little Red Corvette).  I do not want to remove "James Bond" from DF1 if "James Dean" appears in DF2.

Comment: does order matter and can common strings appear anywhere?

Comment: order does not matter and common strings can occur anywhere

Comment: do you want to keep the df2 or can we append to that df?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution below.
For now, it's not very elegant but it works.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Little Red', 'Grow Your', 'James Bond', 'Tom Brady'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Little Red Corvette', 'Grow Your Beans', 'James Dean'])

# For each element of df1, if we found a left(df2, len(df1)) = df1, we
# apply df1 = df2
# Remark that the column name is 0
for i in range(int(df1.count())):
    for j in range(int(df2.count())):
        if df1.loc[i, 0] == df2.loc[j, 0][:len(df1.loc[i, 0])]:
            df1.loc[i, 0] = df2.loc[j, 0]

# Finaly we merge df1 and df2 by union of the keys.
# Here the column name is 0
df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='outer', on=0, sort=True, copy=False)
```

The DataFrame df3 is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could `bisect` the values after sorting:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Little Red', 'Grow Your', 'James Bond', 'Tom Brady'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Little Red Corvette', 'Grow Your Beans', 'James Dean'])

from bisect import bisect_left

def find_common(df1, df2):
    vals = df2.values
    vals.sort(0)
    for i, row in df1.iterrows():
        val = row.values
        ind = bisect_left(vals, val, hi=len(vals) - 1)
        if val[0] not in vals[ind][0]:
            yield val[0]


df3 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame(find_common(df1, df2)),ignore_index=True)
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
                     0
0      Grow Your Beans
1           James Dean
2  Little Red Corvette
3           James Bond
4            Tom Brady
```

sorting gives you a `O(N log N)` solution as opposed to `O(n^2)` iterating over every string in df1 every time you get a check a string from df2

Comment: Hi Padraic,  trying to implement your code -- the title of the columns in each DF are called "Phrases".  Your code works but it does not create a single column and I was wondering how I can get that as the output?

Comment: You just want aa dataframe with a single co!um using the phrases column from df1 and df2?

Comment: exactly, your code works if i change all of the column naming convention to zero -- its not a huge deal but I'm just curious how to do it

Comment: Just create the dataframe using vals= df2.Phrases.values etc... Same with df1 just access the Phrases co!umn when iterating

Answer (score 1):

I would first do an outer merge on the dataframes. I am not sure whether `DF1` refers to the column name or the dataframe varaiable name in your posting, but for simplicity I assume you have two dataframes which have columns with strings:

```
df1 
#        words
#0  little red
#1   grow your
#2  james bond
#3  tom brandy

df2 
#                 words
#0  little red corvette
#1      grow your beans
#2           james dean
#3               little
```

Next, make a new dataframe that merges these two (use an outer merge). This takes care of the duplicates

```
df3 = pandas.merge( df1, df2, on='words', how='outer')
#                 words
#0           little red
#1            grow your
#2           james bond
#3           tom brandy
#4  little red corvette
#5      grow your beans
#6           james dean
#7               little
```

Next you want to use the [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) method:

```
dummies = df3.words.str.get_dummies(sep='')
#   grow your  grow your beans  james bond  james dean  little  little red  \
#0          0                0           0           0       1           1   
#1          1                0           0           0       0           0   
#2          0                0           1           0       0           0   
#3          0                0           0           0       0           0   
#4          0                0           0           0       1           1   
#5          1                1           0           0       0           0   
#6          0                0           0           1       0           0   
#7          0                0           0           0       1           0   

#   little red corvette  tom brandy  
#0                    0           0  
#1                    0           0  
#2                    0           0  
#3                    0           1  
#4                    1           0  
#5                    0           0  
#6                    0           0  
#7                    0           0
```

Notice, if a string contains no other sub-strings in the `words` column, or if is the super-string of 1 or more sub-strings, then it's column will sum to 1 -  otherwise it will sum to a number > 1. Now you can use this `dummies` dataframe to find the indices corresponding to the sub-strings and remove them:

```
bad_rows = [where(df3.words==word)[0][0] 
            for word in list(dummies) 
            if dummies[word].sum() > 1 ]  # only substrings will sum to greater than 1
#[1, 7, 0]

df3.drop( df3.index[bad_rows] , inplace=True)
#                 words
#2           james bond
#3           tom brandy
#4  little red corvette
#5      grow your beans
#6           james dean
```

Note- this takes care of the case where you have more than 1 sub-string of a super-string. For instance `'little'`, `'little red'` are both sub-strings of the super-string `'little red corvette'`, so I assume you would only keep the super-string.