# Find phrases stored in a dataframe in sentences found in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

assuming I have 2 dataframes:

```
sub = pd.DataFrame(['Little Red', 'Grow Your', 'James Bond', 'Tom Brady'])
text = pd.DataFrame(['Little Red Corvette must Grow Your ego', 'Grow Your Beans', 'James Dean and his Little Red coat', 'I love pasta'])
```

One containing various subjects and the other text from where I should be able to extract the subjects

I want the output of text dataframe to be:

```
Text                                    | Subjects
Little Red Corvette must Grow Your ego  | Little Red, Grow Your
Grow Your Beans                         | Grow Your
James Dean and his Little Red coat      | Little Red
I love pasta                            | NaN
```

Any idea how I can achieve this? 
I was looking at this question: [Check if words in one dataframe appear in another (python 3, pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465552/check-if-words-in-one-dataframe-appear-in-another-python-3-pandas)
but it is not exactly as my desired output. Thankyou

Comment: First of all, good question! that is precisely the expected style

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with joined all values of `sub` by `|` with regex word boundary:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in sub[0])
text['new'] = text[0].str.findall(pat).str.join(', ')
print (text)
                                        0                    new
0  Little Red Corvette must Grow Your ego  Little Red, Grow Your
1                         Grow Your Beans              Grow Your
2      James Dean and his Little Red coat             Little Red
3                            I love pasta
```

If want `NaN` for not matched values use `loc`:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in sub[0])
lists = text[0].str.findall(pat)
m = lists.astype(bool)
text.loc[m, 'new'] = lists.loc[m].str.join(',')
print (text)
                                        0                   new
0  Little Red Corvette must Grow Your ego  Little Red,Grow Your
1                         Grow Your Beans             Grow Your
2      James Dean and his Little Red coat            Little Red
3                            I love pasta                   NaN
```